# Grails+SpringSecurity+CAS doesn't redirect to targetUrl after Authentication

Tags: grails, spring-security

I set up a simple Grails site (uses SSL) on localhost, configured spring security and set up users with s2-quickstart. Then I configured it to use CAS server authentication. It does seem to authenticate, as per the CAS logs, but after authentication, keeps going back to the index.gsp page of the grails app, instead of the requested URL. Here's the configuration in application.groovy.

```
// Added by the Spring Security Core plugin:  
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName = 'com.helloworld.SecUser'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.authorityJoinClassName = 'com.helloworld.SecUserSecRole'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.authority.className = 'com.helloworld.SecRole'

grails.plugin.springsecurity.providerNames = ['casAuthenticationProvider']

grails.plugin.springsecurity.cas.active = true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.cas.sendRenew = false
grails.plugin.springsecurity.cas.loginUri = '/login'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.cas.serviceUrl = 'https://localhost:8080/'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.cas.serverUrlPrefix = 'https://localhost:8443/cas'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.cas.serverUrlEncoding = 'UTF-8'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.cas.key = 'grails-spring-security-cas'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.cas.artifactParameter = 'ticket'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.cas.serviceParameter = 'service'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.cas.filterProcessesUrl = '/j_spring_cas_security_check'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.cas.proxyCallbackUrl = 'https://localhost:8080/secure/receptor'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.cas.proxyReceptorUrl = '/secure/receptor'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.cas.useSingleSignout = true


grails.plugin.springsecurity.cas.logout.afterLogoutUrl = 'https://localhost:8443/cas/logout?url=https://localhost:8080/logout'

grails.plugin.springsecurity.logout.postOnly = false

  grails.plugin.springsecurity.successHandler.alwaysUseDefaultTargetUrl = false

grails.plugin.springsecurity.interceptUrlMap = [
    '/js/**': ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'],
    '/css/**': ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'],
    '/images/**': ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'],
    '/login/**': ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'],
    '/logout/**': ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'],
    '/secure/receptor': ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'],  // <- allows CAS to contact the receptor
    '/**': ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY']
]
```

Can you suggest what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, grails.plugin.springsecurity.cas.serviceUrl value should end with /j_spring_cas_security_check.

We use:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.cas.active = true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.cas.loginUri = "/login"
grails.plugin.springsecurity.cas.serverUrlPrefix = "<cas server url>"
grails.plugin.springsecurity.cas.serviceUrl = "<grails server url>/j_spring_cas_security_check"
grails.plugin.springsecurity.cas.proxyCallbackUrl = null
grails.plugin.springsecurity.cas.proxyReceptorUrl = null
```

I've also found it helpful to go with minimal configuration initially just to get things working. I've locked my grails server up by over-configuring different plugins with what I thought were good values from the get-go numerous times.

Comment: hi, thks for replying... i removed everything from the application.groovy except the above and the first three lines from spring security.

Comment: keeps looping between https://localhost:8443/cas/login?service=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fj_spring_cas_security_check and https://localhost:8080/j_spring_cas_security_check?ticket=ST-242-4sL7gAeowKHL9CAl6uyO-cas01.example.org

Comment: Odd. I use those settings with a local Jasig CAS server deployed at https://localhost:8443/cas (my cas server url value). The loginUri is just "/login". We also set grails.plugin.springsecurity.useSessionFixationPrevention = false.

Comment: could it be related to the interceptUrlMap, controllerAnnotations or the filterChain.chainMap?